# User has insufficient privileges on the page on facebook even if login through admin

Tags: facebook-graph-api

> {    "error": {
>         "message": "(#10) User has insufficient privileges on the page.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 10,
>         "fbtrace_id": "GoRNu/X/zoq"    } }

Comment: this is quite broad, please include a lot more details in your questions on stackoverflow. for example, the relevant parts of your code would be the absolute minimum. read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You ask for permissions with the scope parameter. It is a comma separated list of permissions. Visit the below url to get more information.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#login
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions